# System hangs up on OpenGLES calls

Tags: c++, opengl-es

I want to draw simple triangle using OpenGLES (Win32/C++/VS2010).
So I have not got any errors, but system hangs up on OpenGLES calls.

I can compile and run different game engines on my machine and all went ok, but I can't draw a simple triangle!

Game loop still run, so I receive update and draw events and I see my triangle, but OpenGLES calls so slow, that system hangs up!

```
1.  Creating and initializing EGL stuff.

2.  glViewport(0, 0, 800, 480);

3.  glClearColor(/*black*/);

4.  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

5.  GLfloat vertices[] = {1,0,0, 0,1,0, -1,0,0};

6.  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

7.  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);

8.  glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

9.  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

10. glFlush();

11. eglSwapBuffers(...)
```

---

Game log shows something really strange!

```
NO TAG:     Updated:    0ms.
NO TAG:     Rendered:   0ms.
NO TAG:     Updated:    1ms.
NO TAG:     Rendered:   1ms.
NO TAG:     Updated:    0ms.
NO TAG:     Rendered:   0ms.
NO TAG:     Updated:    1ms.
NO TAG:     Rendered:   1ms.
NO TAG:     Updated:    0ms.
NO TAG:     Rendered:   1ms.
NO TAG:     Updated:    1ms.
NO TAG:     Rendered:   0ms.
NO TAG:     Updated:    567ms.
NO TAG:     Rendered:   478ms.
```

There is a slow draw and update call every for examle 50-th loop.

Comment: What do you mean hangs up? Do you get an error? Or hard crash and reboot?

Comment: Not, there is no coredump or error or rebooting. Just SYSTEM hangs up, so all on the screen freezes and I can't doing anythig.

Comment: I have got Intel i7 and 16 Gb RAM. PS: I can debug this small application, and all went ok when I make these calls step by step.

Comment: Hmm. There's nothing wrong that I see there, nor should any incorrect usage of opengl cause such a catastrophic system failure that I can think of. Seems like some kind of system bug or bad gpu/memory or something.

Comment: I can't understand, why the same construction runs prefect when I use any of game engines(irrlicht, cocos2dx).

Comment: Can you just post your actual real code of your program? Maybe you're just in an infinite loop or something.

Comment: Which OpenGL ES implementation are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was in missing these lines:

```
if (! m_hAccelTable || ! TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, m_hAccelTable, &msg))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

Now, my application do not hangs up, but it renders nothing.